# Open data of 1 million or more names, for fuzzy matching experiments

Tags: data-request, names

I am doing some experiments on fuzzy matching and need a set of 1M or more names.  They can be anything, basically: people, plants, addresses, concepts, as long as they look real, i.e. not synthetic and there are lot's of them.

Comment: From the [Twitter API Public Stream](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/get/statuses/sample) you have "user name", which is not @screen_name, and is mainly real names (e.g. Joe Smith). You can collect 1 milliion pretty fast with the 1% sample feed.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I tried the given request https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json and was asked for a userid and password.  My Twitter account did not work there, what kind of an account do I need?  OAuth?  How would I obtain it?

Comment: First you need to create a [developer account](https://dev.twitter.com/), then you need to create an ["app"](https://apps.twitter.com/), then go to the Keys tab and copy your Consumer Key and Secret, and generate Access Token and Key. In total, it's 4 hashed strings that you need. The [python-twitter Readme](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) has good instructions and if you use that package, after authentication there is only one function call: `api.GetStreamSample()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Wikipedia

Wikipedia let you download the data conveniently, without API limits, so you can get the titles of their 4M+ English articles. Depending on your needs, you can try other languages as well. See

http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps

In particular, file `*-all-titles-in-ns0.gz`.

### Alexa One Top Million Websites

These are domain names, though not sure it meets your requirements.

http://s3.amazonaws.com/alexa-static/top-1m.csv.zip